# How to Iterate JSON data as Parameter in Jasper Report

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I'm new in using JasperReport.
I have a simple JSON data that structured like this :

```
[
  {"name":"Data 1"},
  {"name":"Data 2"},
  {"name":"Data 3"}
]
```

I pass that json Data **as Parameter** in Jasper Report.
I'm really new in JasperReport, and i never use Java before. I also use [PHPJasper](https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper) to generate the report.

Now, the problem is :

1. How to iterate over the JSON data in JasperReport?
2. In order to achieve the iterating process, what **type of Class** of the Parameter that will receive the JSON data?

Can anybody help me to solve those problems? I appreciate any answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for [Jasper report iterate over array list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8080667/4595934).

Comment: @Ravikumar My data is in JSON, can Java accept JSON in their ArrayList type?
Also, based on the link you referenced, itshorty wrote '$P{arrayList}', what type/class of the arrayList parameter?